# When should I use resource or @property_hash in a Puppet provider?

Tags: puppet

When writing a Puppet provider, there are two ways to access properties of the resource: the `resource` variable, and the `@property_hash` variable. I'm trying to use a property `foo` in a setter, and started by using `resource[:foo]`. This works when doing

```
puppet apply
```

and it works when doing

```
puppet resource thing thingname
```

but if I try

```
puppet resource thing thingname foo=Foo
```

then `resource[:foo]` is unset. `@property_hash[:foo]` has the right value.
I can print out the value of `foo` right before calling `new` in `self.instances`, and it is correct in both cases.

[This article](http://garylarizza.com/blog/2013/12/15/seriously-what-is-this-provider-doing/) shows `resource` being used all over the place. It's in a function called from `flush`, so I changed all my setters to work with `flush`, but still `resource[:foo]` isn't set.

I can use `@property_hash[:foo]`, but a colleague found that that didn't work when creating a resource - not a problem in my case, as the resource is only managed not created - but I really need to understand this properly to avoid problems in the future. When should I use `resource` and when `@property_hash`? And why does `resource` work in that example but not for me?

Comment: `resource` worked for me whenever I needed it. Also note there is a difference between a parameter attribute and a property attribute, which may explain the issue your colleague had https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/type.html#attributes-parameters-properties